# check voucher number in database if it is correct then insert the subscribers data into another database

Tags: mysql, database

Hi i have 2 database one for voucher numbers and the other one for the new users
and i need from the subscribers to insert the voucher number if the number is correct then they can complete the registration and if not they will be asked to make sure from the voucher number they have and i use this code but it is very weak and did not work

```
    <?php
    $username = "salbota";
    $password = "lK8tFIGAJ_Jp";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("salbota_users", $dbhandle);

    $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];
    $mycardnum = $_POST['cardnum'];

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $mycardnum = stripslashes($mycardnum);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cardnumbers WHERE cardnumo='$mycardnum'";
    if($mycardnum = $_POST['cardnum']){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, cardnum) VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$mycardnum')");
    }else{
        echo 'card number is not correct';
    }


    mysql_close();
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Signup!</h1>
            <form action="new_user.php" method="POST">
                <p>Username:</p><input type="text" name="user" />
                <p>Password:</p><input type="password" name="pass" />
                <p>Card Number:</p><input type="text" name="cardnum" />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Signup!" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your variables in the `INSERT` query are wrong. Instead of `('$user', '$pass', '$mycardnum')`, it should be `('$myusername', '$mypassword', '$mycardnum')`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables in the `INSERT` query are wrong. Instead of `('$user', '$pass', '$mycardnum')`, it should be `('$myusername', '$mypassword', '$mycardnum')`.

Also, the check for *"insert the voucher number if the number is correct the"* doesn't seem to be anywhere in your code. Nor are you checking the `vouchers` table.

Edits after comment:

You've got a query `$query = "SELECT * FROM cardnumbers WHERE cardnumo='$mycardnum'";` but you're not executing it.

And then you're checking `if($mycardnum = $_POST['cardnum']){` but that just checks the same cardnumber which you did `stripslashes` on - so they won't match anyway. Instead you need to execute the query and check if you get the correct cardnumber. Also, your `if` check needs to be two `==` signs, not one.

There are too many non-related issues for why your code won't work. I don't think you'll get an answer on StackOverflow. Fix the above and try again.

Comment: yes you are right but i was wrong when i said 2 database it is 2 tables but but i still facing the same problem after i change the variables

Comment: Added some info to my answer. There are too many non-related issues for why your code won't work. I don't think you'll get an answer on StackOverflow. Fix the above and try again.